# how to avoid duplicate in the code using generics or Function classes

Tags: java, generics

```
private <Y> void meth(
            MyObj ds, MultiValueMap<String, List> mvm, Class<Y> data) {

            

        if(data.isAssignableFrom(Employee.class)) {
            for (Employee rd : (List<Employee>) mvm.get(0).get(1)) {
               
                for (String cName : (List<String>) mvm.get(0).get(0)) {
                    ds.setCellValue((String)rd.getDataElement(cName));
                   
                }
               
            }
        }

        if(data.isAssignableFrom(Department.class)) {
            for (Department rd : (List<Department>) mvm.get(0).get(1)) {
               
                for (String cName : (List<String>) mvm.get(0).get(0)) {
                    ds.setCellValue((String)rd.getDataElement(cName));
                    
                }
               
            }
        }
        
        
        //some more similar if conditions as above
        
}
```

In above, I have like similar 10 if conditions, how to avoid duplicate code in above? Do I need to use any Java 8 Function classes as parameters to avoid duplicate code (or) have to use any extra generics code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While generic methods can be applied, they won't solve the actual scenario you're trying to solve for (an earlier edit of this answer was an attempt before I thought through it more).

Taking a step back, this looks like the problem statement ("what" you're solving for, not "how"):

- Iterate all lists present in a map – in your posted code, this would be: `MultiValueMap<String, List> mvm`
- Accomodate different object types – you posted Employee and Department as examples
- Whatever the list contains (Employee, Department, etc), you want to call `getDataElement()`

As the other answer by Ausgefuchster describes, this can be solved with interfaces. I voted that answer up, but wanted to provide more
more detail and examples.

### Step 1: define an interface

Regardless of concrete class, your map contains lists of things which have `getDataElement()`, so make an interface which captures that:

```
interface HasDataElement {
    String getDataElement();
}
```

### Step 2: classes implement the interface

For this answer, I made up a few simple classes – A, B, and C – which implement the interface, but otherwise only return a string when `getDataElement()` is called. In your code, you would modify Employee, Department, etc. to implement your new interface.

```
class A implements HasDataElement {
    @Override
    public String getDataElement() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B implements HasDataElement {
    @Override
    public String getDataElement() {
        return "B";
    }
}

class C implements HasDataElement {
    @Override
    public String getDataElement() {
        return "C";
    }
}
```

### Step 3: handle the map

I'm using built-in types, so `Map<String, List>` instead of your posted code which uses `MultiValueMap<String, List>`. I think this difference is not significant, but pointing it out anyway.

The method signature below specifies that the map isn't just `<String, List>`, but further specifies that the list itself must contain things which extend the `HasDataElement` interface: `List<? extends HasDataElement>`.

Inside the method, the same `List<? extends HasDataElement>` type shows up in the first loop.

Once inside, the concrete class of `item` isn't relevant – we know it conforms to the `HasDataElement` interface, so we can call `item.getDataElement()`.

```
private static void processAllDataElements(Map<String, List<? extends HasDataElement>> map) {
    for (List<? extends HasDataElement> list : map.values()) {
        for (HasDataElement item : list) {
            System.out.println(item.getDataElement());
        }
    }
}
```

### Example usage

Here's a simple example, along with output, that creates a few different lists of the various classes A, B, and C. It then creates a map and adds all three lists.

```
List<A> listOfA = List.of(new A[]{new A()});
List<B> listOfB = List.of(new B[]{new B(), new B()});
List<C> listOfC = List.of(new C[]{new C(), new C(), new C()});

Map<String, List<? extends HasDataElement>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", listOfA);
map.put("B", listOfB);
map.put("C", listOfC);

processAllDataElements(map);

A
B
B
C
C
C
```

Comment: for (T rd : (List<T>) mvm.get(0).get(1)) {
          rd.something()  //getting compile error here, may I know how to fix this?
        }    

for this pie

Comment: Which version of JDK are you using? I've tried 11 and 17, both work fine.

Comment: Oh, it's not due to JDK version. Taking another look. This solution might not work for you after all. I didn't replicate all of your code since I don't have the various other classes (Employee, etc.) but yes, once nside the loop, `rd` is of type `T` so type info is lost. I'll see if I can modify this to work for you.

Comment: @John – I rewrote the solution based on interfaces. My prior approach using generic methods didn't solve the complete problem you're trying to solve. Also, in my prior approach (as well as in your posted code) there was a "smell" of using both generics and Classes to accomodate the different object types (Employee, etc). By using interfaces, there is less code, and no more passing the Class around. Also, it will work with new objects (beyond Employee) as long as they implement the same new interface.

Comment: In my code, I dont have any interfaces, all Iam using domain classes like Employee, Department etc , then in this case, how to resolve pls?

Comment: So, you don’t have any interfaces, and you can’t _add_ interfaces either? If that really isn’t possible, then you would need to construct your “mvm” map differently, or the lists inside differently, or go back using generic methods (like in my earlier edit) along with reflection to find - at runtime - whether each object has a “getDataElement()” method available (and if so, invoke it).

Answer (score 4):

So it looks like that what you need is inheritance and not generics.
In your if condition you always cast and call the same method on the Object.
So what you can do is e.g. define an interface looking something like this:

```java
public interface MyInterface {
    String getDataElement(String name);
}
```

And implement it in your Employee, Department and other classes you have.

---

If the method always does the same you can use default or an abstract class to not always write the same:

```java
public interface MyInterface {
    default String getDataElement(String name) {
        //do your thing
        return value;
   }
}
```

```java
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public String getDataElement(String name) {
        //do your thing
        return value;
   }
}
```

Now you can change your `meth` method to this:

```java
private void meth(MyObj ds, MultiValueMap<String, List> mvm) {
    List<MyInterface> list = (List<MyInterface>) mvm.get(0).get(1));

    for (MyInterface rd : list) {
        List<String> cNames = (List<String>) mvm.get(0).get(0);
        for (String cName : cNames) {
            ds.setCellValue((String) rd.getDataElement(cName));
        }
    } 
}
```